# How to enable SSL in Jboss 5.1.0

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jax-ws, jboss5.x

can someone please list the steps to enable SSL in Jboss 5.1.0 A.S for JAX-WS web services?
tried editing the server.xml but does not work

Answer (score 2):

Before you edit server.xml, make sure nothing is using it, as you might not be able to save the changes you will make. Also, make sure you remove the comment tags around the connector entry:

```
<!-- SSL Connector on Port 8443 -->
<!--
<Connector
className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector"
port="8443" minProcessors="5"
maxProcessors="75"
enableLookups="false"
acceptCount="10"
connectionTimeout="60000" debug="0"
scheme="https" secure="true">
className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteServerSocketFactory"
clientAuth="false" protocol="TLS"
keystoreFile=/"insert path to the keystore here">
keystorePass="insert keystore password here"/>
</Connector>
-->
```

then restart JBoss